# adding one hot encoding throws error in previously working code in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, one-hot-encoding

```py
with tf.variable_scope("rnn_seq2seq"):

    w = tf.get_variable("proj_w", [num_units, seq_width])
    w_t = tf.transpose(w)
    b = tf.get_variable("proj_b", [seq_width])
    output_projection=(w,b)

    output,state = rnn_seq2seq(enc_inputs,dec_inputs,cell,output_projection=output_projection,feed_previous=False)

    weights=[tf.ones([batch_size * dec_steps])]
    loss=[]
    for i in xrange(dec_steps -1):
        logits = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(output[i],output_projection[0],output_projection[1])
```

If I introduce one hot encoding on the logits here, the program gives error later although both returns the same dimensions. **If I comment out this line, the program does not give any error.**

```py
    prev = logits
        logits = tf.to_float(tf.equal(prev,tf.reduce_max(prev,reduction_indices=[1],keep_dims=True)))
        print prev
        print logits

Tensor("rnn_seq2seq/xw_plus_b:0", shape=TensorShape([Dimension(800), Dimension(14)]), dtype=float32)

Tensor("rnn_seq2seq/ToFloat:0", shape=TensorShape([Dimension(800), Dimension(14)]), dtype=float32)
```

Rest of code:

```py
    crossent =tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits,dec_inputs[i+1],name="SequenceLoss/CrossEntropy{0}".format(i))
    loss.append(crossent)

cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.add_n(loss))
final_state = state[-1]
tvars = tf.trainable_variables()

grads,norm = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tf.gradients(cost,tvars),5)
lr = tf.Variable(0.0,name="learningRate")
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads,tvars))
```

---> 23     grads,norm = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tf.gradients(cost,tvars),5)

> ValueError: List argument 'values' to 'Pack' Op with length 0 shorter
>   than minimum length 1.

Answer (score 3):

Neural networks can only be trained if all the operations they perform are differentiable. The "one-hot" step you apply is not differentiable, and hence such a neural network cannot be trained using any gradient descent-based optimizer (= any optimizer that tensor flow implements).

The general approach is to use `softmax` (which is differentiable) during training to approximate one-hot encoding (and your model already has `softmax` following computing logits, so commenting out the "one-hot" is actually all you need to do).

Comment: Thanks for coming again for my rescue :)

Comment: However, even when I comment out the line, the learning is not happening - cost remains the same  and the norm is printed as Inf. Any way to debug this ?

Comment: I would start by setting non-zero learning rate here: `lr = tf.Variable(0.0,name="learningRate")`. If that doesn't help then I don't know, I have no experience debugging tensor flow models :(

Comment: ohh.. have substituted with nonzero numbers as well ( was using placeholder earlier) , but no effect on learning. am trying to figure out what could cause the norm to be inf .

Comment: Interestingly, substituting LSTM cell with GRUCell made it learn.